# Ruby send a method call to a block

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if you could `yield` a method call in Ruby. What I would like to do is the following:

```
do_in_thread { send_http_request(result) }


def do_in_thread
    Thread.new { yield }
end
```

I basically want that method to be called in a `Thread` if the method is inside the block of the method `do_in_thread()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it already doing so?

```
def do_in_thread
    Thread.new { yield }
end

puts Thread.current.id
# 70059539355960
do_in_thread { puts Thread.current.id }
# 70059432631980
```

Comment: Ah this example makes a lot more sense than my use case. I wasn't sure whether the HTTP request was being done on the main Thread or the worker Thread.